# Can the derivative prove my function has only one root?

Tags: calculus, functions

I have a function:
$$f(x)=x-\ln(x^2+1)+2$$

I want to prove my function has exactly one root. If I differentiate:
$$f'(x)=1-\frac{2x}{x^2+1}$$ I can see this value is positive for every $x$. Does this prove that my function is strictly increasing? All the theorems I know about the argument apply for a closed interval, so I don't know if my resolution is valid.  Should I also prove the function has a positive and a negative part?

Comment: You could make a graph of the derivative with a graphing tool and see what happens

Comment: The derivative is $0$ at $1$, but that makes no difference, the function is strictly increasing. You do need something like an Intermediate Value Theorem argument to show it has a root.

Comment: Note that $\ln(x^2 + 1) \approx 2 \ln |x|$. Could you prove this is the function were simple $\ln$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you know the derivative is positive everywhere, then you know the function has *at most one root* -- for example, you can reason that if it had two different roots, then the mean value theorem says that $f'(x)=0$ for some $x$ between those roots, which you know isn't the case.

Unfortunately, in this case you need a little more finesse than that, because $f'(1)=0$, as André observed. However, the argument still shows that there can't be two roots on the same side of $1$ -- and you can easily calculate that $f(1)>0$, so another application of the MVT shows that there can't be a root greater than $1$.

But you need to argue separately that the function has *at least one* root. The intermediate value theorem will do that for you if you show that the function has both a positive and a negative value.

Comment: How can i choose two helpful values for the theorem?

Comment: @Marco: Two helpful values for which theorem?

Comment: @Marco: Our function is negative at $-88$.

Comment: @Henning I was confusing with Bolzano's theorem

Comment: @Marco Make a graph of the original function to determine suitable values to support the intermediate value theorem

Comment: @imranfat Is an exercise supposed to be solved without pc's or calculators

Comment: @Marco: Back in my time all one needed to make a graph was a piece of graph paper and a pencil ...

Comment: I did not know that. But in general, graphs (and yours is easy) are not used to prove something (depending on the setting) but they can greatly help to aid a algebraic proof. Graphs help a lot in the learning process and very often this is ignored.

Comment: The mean value theorem is fine, but it seems easier to notice that $f(0) = 2 > 0$ while $\lim _{x \to -\infty} f(x) = -\infty$, so $f$ surely has a root in $(-\infty, 0)$ (being continuous).

Comment: I think the second paragraph is a little unnecessarily complicated. The derivative being nonnegative everywhere and zero in only finitely many places guarantees the function is strictly increasing. (Or, I suppose, zero on a set of points where each as a neighborhood around it where the function is strictly positive.)

Comment: @6005: It will work, I think, as long as the zeroes form a closed set with dense complement (and of course we get the "closed" part for free if the derivative is is continuous). But I was aiming to avoid having to argue for that for a reader who doesn't already know.

Answer (score 3):

$g(x)=\log(1+x^2)$ is a convex function on $(-1,1)$ and a concave function on $(-\infty,-1)$ and $(1,+\infty)$, since:
$$ g''(x) = 2\frac{1-x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}. $$
By computing the bevaviour in a neighbourhood of $x=1$, we have that $g(x)\leq x$ for any $x\geq 0$, hence the only solutions of $g(x)=x+2$ have to belong to $\mathbb{R}^-$. Over $\mathbb{R}^-$ $g(x)$ is a decreasing function and $x+2$ is an increasing function: by comparing the behaviours in a left neighbourhood of $x=0$ and in a right neighbourhood of $-\infty$ we get that $g(x)=x+2$ has a unique (negative) real solution. Few steps of Newton's method with starting point $-1$ give that such a root is $\approx -1.15369622$.